# How to extract comments from Facebook App

Tags: wordpress, facebook, facebook-comments

In my WordPress website using **Wpdevart Facebook comments** plugin for embedding Facebook comment. Now I need to extract comment in an XL file. How to I can do it?

I have tried with the https://exportcomments.com tool. It can extract Facebook comment from a website URL. But it's not working properly.

Have any suggestion (code, plugin or tool) to extracting comments from the Facebook app?

Comment: afaik there´s no way to export comments from the comments plugin. stackoverflow is no place to ask for finished software though, this is for developers only, i´m afraid.

Answer (score 0):

That used to be possible up to and including API v3.2, as described under https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/faqs#faq_1603507626630008

> The comments for every URL can be accessed via the Graph API. Simply make an HTTP GET request to:
>
> `https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/?fields=og_object{comments}&id=<YOUR_URL>&access_token=<YOUR_TOKEN>`

That doesn’t appear to work in v3.3 any more though, only results in an error message saying,

> (#100) Tried accessing nonexisting field (comments) on node type (OpenGraphObject)

I can’t find an explicit mention of this in the changelog right now though.

---

And even in API versions prior to v3.3, it seems you can only get the created time and message (plus maybe a couple of other meta fields), but specifically `from` – info about the actual user making the comment – is not available any more.